# Can't start external application

Tags: android, android-intent, start-activity

I've got the following code to start external applications but it's not working:

```
private fun launchApplication(packageName: String)
{
    try
    {
        val application = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)
        startActivity(application)
    }
    catch (ex: Exception) { }
}
```

I've tried with the following packages:

- com.google.android.youtube
- com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

With the code from @Mayur Gajra it is working with `com.google.android.youtube` but not with `com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market`, throwing the following error:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
> Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
> cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x4000000
> pkg=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market }

But if i search packages installed with the following code, TeamViewer shows up:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null)
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
val appsList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)
```

> ResolveInfo{40c33b1 com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market/com.teamviewer.quicksupport.ui.QSActivity m=0x108000}

- packageName = com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market
- className = com.teamviewer.quicksupport.QSApplication

Any ideas?

Comment: On Android 11? .

Comment: You should try to launch an app of yourself.

Comment: @blackapps Android 8.1

Comment: `but it's not working:` It is unclear what you mean with 'not working'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved with the following code:

```
private fun launchApplication(packageName: String)
{
    try
    {
        // Find application with that package name
        val mainIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null)
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
        val pkgAppsList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0)
        val application = pkgAppsList.first { it.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName == packageName }

        // Start that application
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.setClassName(application.activityInfo.packageName, application.activityInfo.name)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    catch (ex: Exception) { }
}
```

Some aditional comments: this method won't work if application is in [Lock Task Mode](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode), remember to call `stopLockTask()` before.

Comment: Is it possible to start an unattended session in TeamViewer using a URI passed via Intent?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way & let system find the activity with `Launcher` category of that package & start it.

```
private fun launchApplication(packageName: String) {
        try {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
            intent.setPackage(packageName)
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            startActivity(intent)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not working. in fact, not even the application selector comes up.

Comment: @Lechucico What's the device model & API level that you're testing on?

Comment: Its Android 8.1, API min 21, target 28

Comment: @Lechucico That's strange. I tested on multiple devices & it works. Can you please print the exception(`ex.printStackTrace()`) you get after applying my code?

Comment: There's no exception, it just continues without doing anything.

Comment: Can you please update your question with my code tried? How you used it & where are you using it? Activity, Fragment? Also, Can you please tell me which company phone are you using & model name? @Lechucico

Comment: I've updated with more information. There was an error, but for somereason I didn't see that.